# FastAPI - Cannot use `Response` as a return type when `status_code` is set to 204

Tags: python, fastapi

I've been using the following code for my `/healthz`:

```py
@router.get("/healthz", status_code=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT, tags=["healthz"],
            summary="Service for 'Health Check'",
            description="This entrypoint is used to check if the service is alive or dead.",
            # include_in_schema=False
            )
def get_healthz() -> Response:
    return Response(status_code=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

This has been working since some years ago.

Today I updated FastAPI from 0.88.0 to 0.89.0 and now I get `AssertionError: Status code 204 must not have a response body`. The full tracebakc can be seen below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1234, in _handle_fromlist
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "......../src/routers/healthz.py", line 20, in <module>
    @router.get("/healthz", status_code=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT, tags=["healthz"],
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/..../.local/share/virtualenvs/........../lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 633, in decorator
    self.add_api_route(
  File "/Users/..../.local/share/virtualenvs/......../lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 572, in add_api_route
    route = route_class(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/...../.local/share/virtualenvs/....../lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 396, in __init__
    assert is_body_allowed_for_status_code(
AssertionError: Status code 204 must not have a response body
python-BaseException
```

Here:
[image]

My question is:

Is this a bug from the version 0.89.0 , or should I write the `/heathz` In a different way?

Even with `return Response(status_code=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT, content=None)` is failling.

Changelog of 0.89.0:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: I think that you are not following the instructions. The FastAPI constructs the response automatically, the user is not supposed to do it explicitly. In your particular case FastAPI treats the Response you return as an object, and adds this object into automatically constructed response body. :)

Comment: I just saw this fix opened 1h after my question, I'll wait to the merge and test again: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/pull/5860

. If the problem won't be fixed, then I'll put here more details about my implementation. FYI: @Chris alv2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug fixed on the release 0.89.1:
https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/releases/tag/0.89.1